# Want to search occurance of "error" string in a log file except in some strings that has "error"(we should ignore these strings)

Tags: command-line, scripts, dash-shell

I want to search occurance of "error" in log file using if condition and print that error is present in log file. and if not present then should print no error found. The issue here is in my log file is, i have some word that has error as a substring, and i want to ignore these words as they are not counted as an error to be considered..

```
Words are :
"LocalErrorPagePolicy"
"ErrorMapping"
"CustomErrorPagePolicy"
"error=ForceYes"

And also i want to avoid one line where error occurs:
Error details may be seen in the file:
```

And rest occurances of error should be considered.

Any help, highly appreciated!

I tried `grep -v "string"` filename , doesn't work.

Comment: grep worked in late 1980s when I learnt it - still works today.  `-v` inverts match just as `man` page states, it sounds like you want a `|`  (OR & not a pipe command) .. but you'll learn/remember more if you do it yourself.    if you go beyond grep's abilities (which I doubt); use 'egrep' which has more regex [expressions] available.

Comment: i tried a lot, still no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One (very rough) approach is to grep all "error" occurrences:
`grep -i "error" FILENAME`

Explanation:

- `-i`: Filter Case *in*sensitive (RegEx equivalent is the `/i` flag)
- `"error"`: Filter for the term "error"
- `FILENAME`: The file to search in

---

Then filter out those you don't want:

`grep -Eiv "(LocalErrorPagePolicy|ErrorMapping|CustomErrorPagePolicy|error=ForceYes|Error details may be seen in the file:)" FILENAME`

Explanation:

- `-Eiv`: Concatenation of multiple parameters, equivalent of `grep -E -i -v`
- `-E`: Interpret the pattern as an extended regular expression (ERE, see `man grep` for more information)
- `-i`: Filter Case *in*sensitive
- `-v`: Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.

For the Pattern:

- `()`: Parentheses create a matching group
- `|`: The pipe character serves as a logical `or`

This breaks down to "find TERM1 OR TERM2 OR ... OR TERMX" and then discard the lines where those terms are found.

---

If we add those together we get:

`grep -i "error" FILENAME | grep -Eiv (LocalErrorPagePolicy|ErrorMapping|CustomErrorPagePolicy|error=ForceYes|Error details may be seen in the file:)"`

---

To test this I created a very small dummy file:

```
LocalErrorPagePolicy
ErrorMapping
CustomErrorPagePolicy
error=ForceYes
Error details may be seen in the file:
Stackoverflowerror
I like errors
error error
LocalErrorErrorError
CustomErrorErrorPolicy
error=errorYes
I am a successfully output!
```

Result after applying the `grep`-command:

```
Stackoverflowerror
I like errors
error error
LocalErrorErrorError
CustomErrorErrorPolicy
error=errorYes
```

As you can see, the unwanted terms have been filtered successfully.

Comment: Thnaks bro, it works perfect :)